# How to resize image in Ruby and keep the image orientation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, rmagick

I have an image with the width of 400px and height 800px. I need to resize this image on 200px on something (the height is not important, important is the width). I am trying to do that this way:

```
img.resize_to_fill!(200).write(thumb_path)
```

but the result is that the image has the proportions 200px on 200 px. It should be resized appropriately, so the final dimensions should be like 200px on width and 400px on height.

How to do that with the **Magick::Image** library?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Height defaults to the width if not set.

Try

```
img.resize_to_fill!(200, nil).write(thumb_path)
```

Comment: It will probably work. If not try the same but with `resize_to_fit`

Comment: **resize_to_fit** work. But the resized image is really blurry. Any advice here? Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you tell the dimensions of the new image given by `resize_to_fit`?